# como fazer um callback em javascript

Tags: javascript, funções, callback

Preciso fazer uma função de callback chamada aplicar, mas nao entendi como faz ela
alguem pode me ajudar?

Enunciado:
Vamos criar três funções e ver como iniciar a trabalhar com os callbacks.

A primeira função se chamará dobro que receberá um número e retornará o dobro.

A segunda função se chamará triplo que recebera um número e retornará o triplo.

A terceira função será chamada de aplicar e receberá um valor e o nome de uma função como parâmetro. Ela retornará o valor da aplicação da referida função ao valor recebido.

esse é meu codigo mas não entendi como faz a função de callback aplicar:

function dobro(x) {
return 2 * x
};

function triplo(z) {
return 3 * z
};

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Exemplo:

```
function dobro(x) { return 2 * x };

function aplicar(valor, funcao){
 return funcao(valor);
}

aplicar(1, dobro);
```

O resultado será 2;

A ideia no geral é ter uma função que recebe tanto o valor a ser utilizado quando a função que irá processar esse valor, no exemplo pegamos sua função dobro e passamos como um dos parametros da função aplicar, e depois utilizamos essa função para calcular o dobro de 1.

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou muito de verdade, agora consegui entender!! obrigado mesmo de coração